# Sorting characters instead of numeric values in Pivot Chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I want to generate pivot chart from pivot table. The problem here is my pivot table does not contain any numeric values. There are only some characters to differentiate them. So my pivot chart will be sort based on the characters like "A" and "B".I try to put the characters in the values column but it seem to convert it into numeric values. Do you know how to sort the characters instead of numeric values in pivot chart? I don't have any ideas. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In general, all Excel charts require numbers to chart anything. Most charts have a category axis, which can display text, and a value axis, against which the numeric values are plotted. In a XY Scatter chart, both axes are numeric or value axes.

Without numbers, Excel won't be able to plot a chart.

It is not clear what you want the chart to look like. Edit your question with more details about the data and a hand-drawn sketch of what chart you'd expect to create from that. Then I can edit this answer accordingly.